# Ошибка при установке Node - "npm" не является внутренней или внешней командой

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd

Искал решения, но найти не могу. Я установил Node и он работает из установленной директории:

```
$ npm install
```

Но консоль из дочерней папки выдаёт:

> "npm" не является внутренней или внешней командой,
>   исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Простите... Забыл изменить переменную пути в Path

Answer (score 1):

Нужно прописать путь к npm.

В *nix: `~/.profile` или `~/.bash_profile` написать `export PATH="/path/to/npm_dir:$PATH"`